# Why does the axillary nerve have root value of C5 and C6 only and not C5, C6, C7, C8 and T1?

Tags: human-anatomy

Posterior cord is formed by the posterior division of all the three trunks, so shouldn't the root value be all the spinal nerves of the brachial plexus which is the case for radial nerve?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide sources/references that support your question. Why do you think the axillary nerve has fibers from C7, C8, and T1, in addition to C5 and C6?